# Splitting hyperlinks in Angular4

Tags: html, css, json, angular, mean-stack

I am new to angular4 working over MEAN Stack My data is coming from Mongo DB in the form of a list of hyperlinks.Now I want that when I click over each link in UI, it should be opened as a separate link but as of now, it is opening a combined link i.e. it is taking as a single entry.
I am trying to pass ';' after each link in Mongo Db and at the UI level I am trying to separate/split based on each ';'.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
        <td> {{ item.SNo }}</td>
        <td> {{ item.UseCase }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{item.ReferenceMaterials.split(';')}}">{{ item.ReferenceMaterials }}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My structure of JSON is:

```
{
    "_id":"537437505593", 
    "SNo" :"1", 
    "UseCase":"hfwioegepepohgy", 
    "Focus":"hellow world", 
    "RefernceLinks":"link1";"link2";"link3"
}
```

These links are rendered to UI as link1;link2;link3.Clicking over link1 click over all other links also.Kindly help.

Comment: Your json does  not look valid for RefernceLinks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'split'
})
export class SplitPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val:string, separator:string):string[] {
    return val.split(separator);
  }
}
```

And use it like this

```
<a *ngFor="let link of item.ReferenceMaterials|split" href="{{link}}">{{link}}</a>
```

Or item.RefernceLinks like your json shows...

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngFor`.

```
<a *ngFor="let link of item.ReferenceMaterials" href="{{link}}">{{link}}</a>
```